# Python Virtual Enviroment is not using its pip after activation

Tags: python, windows, python-venv

I have encountered problem when after I activate my venv its still not using its pip or python.

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip -V
pip 22.0.4 from 'default python path'
```

Any idea how to solve this not working venv ? Im using Win 10

Thanks for all the replies

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing is about activation. Try to deactivate/activate. You should see your (venv) before cmd line:

```
(venv) C:\Users\...>pip -V
pip 21.3.1 from C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

(venv) C:\Users\...>deactivate
C:\Users\...>venv\Scripts\activate.bat

(venv) C:\Users\...>pip -V     
pip 21.3.1 from C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```